# CryStal Report dialogue box appear on second page

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

When I click on Second Page .. A dialogue Box Opened and asked for login information again

This is the Error Which comes when i clicked on second page
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCCF6.png

here is my code

```
public void LoadReport()
{

        crReportDocument = new ReportDocument();


        connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        ParameterField paramField1 = new ParameterField();

        ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        //p1
        paramField1.Name = "id";
        paramDiscreteValue1.Value = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
        paramField1.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue1);
        paramFields.Add(paramField1);

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReportDocument;
        crReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt"));
        connectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];

        connectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseName"];
        connectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseUserID"];
        connectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBasePasswordName"];

        SetDBLogonForReport(connectionInfo);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
        CrystalReportViewer1.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.EnableParameterPrompt = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;

        DataSet dsTemp = new DataSet();
        DBAccess dbAccess = new DBAccess();
        SqlParameter spId = new SqlParameter("@Id", Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString());
        SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] { spId };
        dsTemp = dbAccess.ExecuteDataset("sp_GetInvestigationData", sqlParams);
        crReportDocument.SetDataSource(dsTemp.Tables[0]);

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReportDocument;
        CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString());


}
private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
{
    TableLogOnInfos tableLogOnInfos = CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
    foreach (TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo in tableLogOnInfos)
    {
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;

    }



}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have same version of crystal report on all places. see if [required packages](http://1800thenerd.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/sap-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010-files-needed-to-download/) are installed  Try this

```
private ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            BindReport();
        }

        private void BindReport()
        {

            rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("report1.rpt"));
            DataSet ds = getReportData();
            rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        }

        private DataSet getReportData()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "GetProductList";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;            
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(ds, "ctable");
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }
```

You may see another example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rsubhajit/CrystalReportwithDataSet03012006060655AM/CrystalReportwithDataSet.aspx)